# postgresql suffixing .00 when round produces whole numbers

Tags: postgresql, format, rounding

I use `postgresql 9.3`. When I round off whole numbers, I want to get results by suffixing .00.

```
SELECT ROUND(12345, 2) //Result:12345
```

How can I get a result like 12345.00

I found numeric formatting functions like `TO_CHAR` can generate such a result.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ROUND(12345, 2), '99999D99') // 12345.00
```

Is there a way to get result in numeric data type itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot and there is also no point. What you are after is a certain *representation* of a numeral and that is exactly what the `to_char()` function does. PG does not care about a `.00` suffix, it's all bits on the inside anyway.

However, if you want to work with an *exact* representation of a real number, you should use the [`numeric` data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) with the appropriate modifiers such as:

```
12345::numeric(7,2)
```

Keep in mind though that the `numeric` data type is very slow compared to the other numeral types such as `integer` and `double`.

Answer (score 1):

This answer has 5 paragraphs.

This answer also has 5.0 paragraphs. Or 5.000.

The number of paragraphs in this answer doesn't change depending on whether you say it is 5 or 5.00, just the string used to represent the number.

`ROUND` returns a number, not a string, so you can't say it did or didn't have a suffix, because numbers don't have suffices. It **does** have a precision of `2`, and e.g. my trying it on pgAdmin III shows it as `12345.00`, but that's up to the tool used with the value examining the precision or not, not to the number.

You can force a value `val` to a precision with `val::numeric(1000, 2)` and so on, but this is already done by `ROUND`, so it's still a matter of whether a given tool will pay attention.